# Is there a way to protect workbooks using openpyxl or xlswriter?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to automate Excel reports, and I'd prefer users didn't try to rename or reorder the worksheets. While I've had no problems protecting individual cells using xlsxwriter, I've failed to see an option to protect the workbook itself. I'm looking to openpyxl, but the tutorial does not seem to have any effect.

Edit: I'm now using this block of code, but does neither produce an error or protect my workbooks.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection

workbook = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
workbook.security = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword = 'secret-password', lockStructure = True)
workbook.save(filepath)
```

By the way, I am dealing with .xlsm files. If there are any solutions or points that I've missed, please let me know.

Comment: do you want only protect the values of your report ...? and you have just one sheet in your xls report ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I have 2 sheets in one report, each containing a different type of a report. What I want to protect is the reordering of Sheet1 and Sheet2 and their names.

Comment: which version openpyxl are you using ?

Comment: I think that you cant do that with files preexisting  ..here an explain https://www.oipapio.com/question-7316305

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this code:

```
from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection

myWorkbook.security = WorkbookProtection(workBookPassword = 'super-secret-password', lockStructure = True)
myWorkbook.save(filepath)
```

Change:

`WorkbookProtection(workBookPassword = 'super-secret-password', lockStructure = True)`

to:

`WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword = 'super-secret-password', lockStructure = True)`

`workBookPassword` should be `workbookPassword`

Tested on Python32 3.8 and OpenPyXL version 3.0.2

Comment: dont work for me.. Have you tried a file that already existed before?

Comment: I was using openpyxl 2.6.3 and upgraded to 3.0.2 and made the correction from workBookPassword to workbookPassword but, I'm still not producing any errors or success.

Comment: @ConSod actually, did you test with .xlsx files or .xlsm files? I'm using .xlsm files and I have a feeling that might be the reason.

Comment: Strange, I tested both xlsx and xlsm files. Have you tried running the code twice?

Comment: Yes, but I just noticed the worksheets I protected using xlsxwriter aren't protected anymore.

Comment: Could you try applying an empty WorkbookProtection() first, and then set the password and lock structure.

Comment: So the worksheets were protected by xlsxwriter, but not the workbook? I tried with a workbook that was not protected beforehand.

Comment: I got it to work by protecting the sheets along with the workbook using openpyxl instead of xlsxwriter. I'm thinking the two of them might've caused some disagreement...I wanted to use xlsxwriter to protect the workbook initially, but I couldn't find any documentation on it, previously.

Comment: "I wanted to use xlsxwriter to protect the workbook initially, but I couldn't find any documentation on it". @upset_undergrad XlsxWriter doesn't support Workbook level protection.

Answer (score 0):

Xlsxwriter has the option to protect the workbook with the command worksheet.protect() (have a look at the documentation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html )

However take into consideration this:

> Worksheet level passwords in Excel offer very weak protection. They do
>   not encrypt your data and are very easy to deactivate. Full workbook
>   encryption is not supported by XlsxWriter since it requires a
>   completely different file format and would take several man months to
>   implement.

Comment: The question is about protecting **existing workbooks**. xlsxwriter cannot read existing workbooks and only does worksheet protection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

```
import xlwings as xw  

wb = xw.Book(r'<path_to_.xlsx file>')

wb.save(password='<your_password>', path=r'<path_to_save_.xlsx file>')
```